# How to project sf object to extract cell data from raster using polygons in exact extractor R

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I need to extract raster cell data on a county basis.

```
dd <- exact_extract(tmax,counties,c('mean','max'))
```

I'm using the exact extractor package, which keeps giving me this warning:

```
Warning message:
In .exact_extract(x, y, fun = fun, ..., include_xy = include_xy,  :
Polygons transformed to raster CRS (EPSG:NA)
```

The county file I have has a CRS of "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs".  I believe this is also known as EPSG 4326.  I even transformed the county polygon file using the following code, and I still get this error.

```
new_sf_counties <- st_transform(sf_counties, crs = 4326)
```

Is this a warning I need to worry about?  If so, how do I fix it?  The county shapefile can be downloaded from https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/COUNTY/.  Thank you.

Comment: Try `crs=st_crs(4326)`. You could also use that proj4string that you are showing in place of 4326 in the st_crs function.

Comment: Tried it, and it doesn't work.  I might try to contact the package developer, as this seems like an important issue.

Comment: What was the error? You may need to convert from sf to sfc for the polygon using st_as_sfc.

Comment: Turns out the fix is to use projectRaster(....) on the raster.  Having said that, I still think that warning needs to be changed/fixed, since the CRS string associated with the raster is the exact same as I'm giving it in projectRaster.  In other words, I'm projecting it to the same projection it's already in.

Answer (score 0):

For me running  `crs(tmax)<-crs(counties)` to secure the crs of the raster data is the same as the crs of the polygones before running `dd <- exact_extract(tmax,counties,c('mean','max'))`  made the warning message disappear.

Comment: I receive the same warning even after forcing that the polygon and raster have the same projection.